# What is the current scheme for naming variables and functions?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

Is there a standard way to name them or is it programmer's call?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your company's coding guidelines; challenge them if they are outdated (i.e. keep a list of changes at the top of the file despite using version control).

If you're the first programmer or doing it for yourself, decide on a set of coding guidelines that works for you, document it, and stick with it.

Comment: Good point. The worst thing you can do is changing the coding style in the middle of the project. Stick to whatever exists... there is nothing more you can do.

Comment: I completely agree. It's like asking what the correct type of power plug is to use in your home. There's not much difference at the end of the day but if every appliance used a different one you'd have lots of trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Something very basic and pretty much universally accepted:

- use nouns for variable names.
- use verbs for function names.

This makes coding easier to understand.

Beyond that, there are lots and lots of "rules" - I suspect the other answers will provide a few.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the naming guidelines posted by the GNU folks; they're similar to many others and about as good:

http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Names.html#Names

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I usually name functions as:

```
MyFunctionToDoSomething();
```

variables/members as:

```
my_var_to_accept_something;
```

global variables:

```
MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE;
```

Above all I try to keep all my naming to this standard. I really don't know what notation this follows, but I'm not a big fan of the Hungarian notation, so...

BTW, I see a lot of people going to some lengths to write small names which later on they wont understand... I learned to don't do that for the same reason. After all most IDE have auto-complete features so using long names isn't really an issue.

Cheers

Comment: Are there any major libraries or applications in C that use PascalCasedFunctionNames()?

Comment: Normally, all upper-case is reserved for macros, not for global variables.

Comment: mcl, I can remember IPP from intel and OpenCV

Jonathan, shure, I know ;) As I said, I really don't follow any strict convention. Obvisouly this can lead to problems when other people start working on my code, but I document how "I want" my code to look like, and they better do as I like (just kidding)

Answer (score 0):

Name your variables **in english**.
Comment **in english**.

But if you must use a different language, then use it for all variables and comments.
Don't mix english (other than keywords and library functions) with your language.

I hate to see [code like](http://www.koders.com/c/fid9BA6128FC3136730EED77F52BE703436E0A60514.aspx):

```
void  FreeT( void* puntero ) {

    unsigned long size;

    size = *(long*) ( (char*)puntero - offset );
//    memcpy( &size ,, offset );
    if ( !size ) return; 
    total_bloques --;
    total_alocado -= size ;
    free( (char*)puntero - offset );
}
```